# Using rlang double curly braces {{ in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, rlang, quasiquotes

## Problem

The `{{}}` operator from the `rlang` package makes it incredibly easy to pass column names as function arguments (aka Quasiquotation). I understand `rlang` is intended to work with `tidyverse`, but is there a way to use `{{}}` in `data.table`?

## Intended use of {{}} with dplyr

```
test_dplyr <- function(dt, col1, col2){
  
  temp <- dt %>%
            group_by( {{col2}} ) %>%
            summarise(test = mean( {{col1}} ))

  return(temp)
}

test_dplyr(dt=iris, col1=Sepal.Length, col2=Species)

> # A tibble: 3 x 2
>   Species     test
>   <fct>      <dbl>
> 1 setosa      5.01
> 2 versicolor  5.94
> 3 virginica   6.59
```

## Failed attempt of using {{}} with data.table

This is ideally what I would like to do, but it returns an ERROR.

```
test_dt2 <- function(dt, col1, col2){
  
  data.table::setDT(dt)
  temp <- dt[, .( test = mean({{col1}})), by = {{col2}} ] )
  return(temp)
}

# error
test_dt2(dt=iris, col1= Sepal.Length, col2= Species)

# and error
test_dt2(dt=iris, col1= 'Sepal.Length', col2= 'Species')
```

## Alternative use of rlang with data.table

And here is an alternative way to use `rlang` with `data.table`. There are two inconvinences here, which are to `rlang::ensym()` every column name variable, and having to call data.table operations inside `rlang::injec()`.

```
test_dt <- function(dt, col1, col2){
  
  # eval colnames
  col1 <- rlang::ensym(col1)
  col2 <- rlang::ensym(col2)
  
  data.table::setDT(dt)
  temp <- rlang::inject( dt[, .( test = mean(!!col1)), by = !!col2] )
  return(temp)
}

test_dt(dt=iris, col1='Sepal.Length', col2='Species')

>       Species  test
> 1:     setosa 5.006
> 2: versicolor 5.936
> 3:  virginica 6.588
```

Comment: There is env arg added in 1.14.3 as an alternative to achieve this kind of flexibility

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think you want to use rlang with data.table.  data.table already has more convenient facilities itself.  Also suggest not using setDT here as that will result in the side effect of changing dt in place.

```
library(data.table)

test_dt <- function(dt, col1, col2) {
  as.data.table(dt)[, .( test = mean(.SD[[col1]])), by = c(col2)]
}

test_dt(dt = iris, col1 = 'Sepal.Length', col2 = 'Species')
##       Species  test
## 1:     setosa 5.006
## 2: versicolor 5.936
## 3:  virginica 6.588
```

This also works:

```
test_dt <- function(dt, col1, col2) {
  as.data.table(dt)[, .( test = mean(get(col1))), by = c(col2)]
}

test_dt(dt=iris, col1='Sepal.Length', col2='Species')
```

Comment: This still requires inputs to be strings, it seems? Is there a way of doing this with a "promise"?

Comment: All arguments to a function are promises.  It is not a good idea to use unevaluated arguments -- using character strings is more flexible .  Then you can pass expressions that evaluate to the name.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the response and the correction.

Comment: Also, in you second function definition, there is a `)` missing at the end of the `j` expression, I think?